# How do `Clicked` and `Command` work when they are both used on the same Xamarin view?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Command` (in my viewModel) and a `Clicked` event (in my code behind) attached to the same view in my `XAML`, and I am noticing some weird results. I am doing this because I would like a view to receive focus right after the code for the command in executed:

1. Do the `Command` and the `Clicked` event execute **synchronously** or **asynchronously**?
2. Are there any adverse effects to using this approach.
3. Is there a better way I could handle this?

Comment: What weird behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Outcome is inconsistent, sometimes it seems the Clicked event is fired before the the command code is executed, and vice versa.

Comment: this is how they generally work, but from what you've said it shouldn't matter which one executes first if you simply want to focus a view. i can't speak for commands, but events are unreliable. they will be handled whenever the system can find time to handle them. normally that's instantaneously, but that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Click events are executed asynchronously. However, I believe the commands are not. They are executed right after the associated action being performed.

My suggestion would be not to use these both together for what you are looking for. Because events will be handled whenever the thread and processor is free. So you cannot rely on it for your requirement as it depends on some other action.

You might achieve what you want by using the Behaviors in Xamarin forms. Refer below links for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating

Comment: Ended up handling it by calling a function (which was assigned to a command) from my view model, but this answer definitely helped, so I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Kikanye

Answer (score 0):

A Xamarin view is a partial class - Separated by View and Code behind

- View(use XAML to create front end)
- Code Behind (write logic)

you can easily write an entire app using View and code behind but it's not practical in the long run.

If you want to use MVVM or MVC you will need to use Binding (separate logic from view )

to answer your question :

**Commands** - best when using MVVM or MVC

**Click Events** - Best for code-behind logic e.g. click a button

[More information about MVVM design patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm)