# Is it better to put my logic in an event handler or in a setter for MVVM (Xamarin `Picker` `SelectedItem` quirks)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**SOLUTION IS IN EDIT OF THE ACCEPTED ANSWER**

I have a view in which has two Pickers, I need to have it so that when the `SelectedItem` property in one Picker changes, the list of Items in the second `Picker` (ItemSource) changes as well.

Currently I have a bound the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` properties of both pickers to properties in my `ViewModel`. In the setter(s) for both of them, I perform the logic needed to change the list of Items in the second picker. The list of Items in the second picker changes successfully, but when I set the `SelectedIndex` (to make it select an Item by default), this fails if the index which I am setting it to is the same as the index which it was on in the previous list. It just shows the `Title` of the Picker instead, this issue seems to be related to [this bug](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1879).

My Code:

- Both Pickers are bound to an Observable collection of strings FYI
- `FrameType` and `DirectionType` are `Enums`
- I initially used only the `SelectedItem` property

Relevant XAML

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
     Text="Direction: " />
     <Picker x:Name="PickerDirection" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                      Title="Select Direction"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Directions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDirection}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedDirectionIndex}"></Picker>

<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
       Text="Frame: "/>
<Picker x:Name="PickerFrame" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                 Title="Select Frame"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Frames}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrame}"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedFrameIndex}"></Picker>
```

Relevant View Model code:

```
public string SelectedDirection
{
    get { return _selectedDirection; }
    set 
    {
        if (Directions.Contains(value))
        {
            if (_selectedDirection != value)
            {
                if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(SelectedFrame) == FrameType.Road &&
                            !DirectionsRoad.Contains(value))
                {
                 _selectedDirection = Directions[Directions.IndexOf(DirectionType.Right.ToString())];
                }
                else
                {
                    _selectedDirection = value;
                }
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public string SelectedFrame
{
    get { return _selectedFrame; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedFrame != value)
        {
            _selectedFrame = value;
            if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(_selectedFrame) == FrameType.Road)
            {
                Directions = DirectionsRoad;
                if (Directions.Contains(SelectedDirection))
                {
                    SelectedDirectionIndex = Directions.IndexOf(SelectedDirection);
                }
                else
                {
                     SelectedDirectionIndex = Directions.IndexOf(DirectionType.Right.ToString());
                }
              }else if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(_selectedFrame) == FrameType.Lane)
              {
                  Directions = DirectionsAll;
                  SelectedDirectionIndex = Directions.IndexOf(SelectedDirection);
              }
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
}

public int SelectedDirectionIndex
{
    get { return _selectedDirectionIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedDirectionIndex != value)
        {
            if (!(value < 0 || value >= Directions.Count))
            {
                _selectedDirectionIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public int SelectedFrameIndex
{
    get { return _selectedFrameIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedFrameIndex != value)
        {
            if (!(value < 0 || value >= Frames.Count))
            {
                _selectedFrameIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The outcome:
[image]

I expect it to never be empty since I ensure that the SelectedDirection is always set to something.

**Notes:**

- I initially used just the `SelectedItem` property, but when I encountered this bug I thought using the `SelectedIndex` property would help to fix it.
- I used `ObservableCollection` to maintain consistency with the other viewModels in the project, and to ensure that the options in the picker are updated when I make changes (based on my understanding you need to use ObservableCollection to make this possible).
- I do plan to refactor the code in the setter for `SelectedFrame` into smaller functions as soon as I get things to work.

Due to this It seems that using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `Picker` would be the only way to fix this. However [the comment by **ottermatic** in this question says that events are unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144365/how-do-clicked-and-command-work-when-they-are-both-used-on-the-same-xamarin). Hence I felt is was better to perform this logic in the setter.

If someone could comment on what I may be doing wrong in my code which is causing this issue and also comment on the pros/cons and/or whether or not I should use the `eventHandler` or have the logic in my setter. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your model with the required relation between the direction and frames? So on a direction you have a frames property with the frame collections. That will make your binding easier as you bind the PickerFrame ItemsSource directly to the PickerDirection SelectedItem property.

Comment: @allan Thanks for the suggestion. I thought of this, but that would involve lots of changes to the project in order to get just this small part to work, and I was hoping to have a solution that wouldn't require such a change

Comment: @Kikanye Could you share a video or the sample link here , I will check it .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT like a vide of what I see when I run the code?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I added a gif, and I hope that was what you needed.

Comment: @Kikanye Glad you have found the solution ! It will be helpful for other people .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see *why* you are using both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex`, but I think what you are trying to achieve can be achieved easier.

First of all, I don't think you need `ObservableCollection` types at all in your example, since you are setting the directions anyway and not modifying the collection. More importantly, fiddling around with the indices is completely unnecessary, as far as I can tell. You are using strings anyway and even though `String` is not a value type, but a reference type, you cannot practically distinguish two `String` instances that have the same content, hence assinging the respective values to `SelectedDirection` and `SelectedFrame` is sufficient.

The following checks seem redundant to me

```cs
if (Directions.Contains(value))


if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(SelectedFrame) == FrameType.Road &&
    !DirectionsRoad.Contains(value))
```

since `Directions` are set to `DirectionsRoad` anyway if `SelectedFrame` has been set to `"Road"`. Hence I'd assume that the second condition won't evaluate to `true` in any case. Hence the `SelectedDirection` can be simplified:

```cs
public string SelectedDirection
{
    get => _selectedDirection;
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedDirection != value && Directions.Contains(value))
        {
            _selectedDirection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Within the setter of `SelectedFrame` there are many things going on, which I'd refactor to methods on it's own right, to improve clarity.

```cs
public string SelectedFrame
{
    get => _selectedFrame;
    set
    {
        if (_selectedFrame != value)
        {
            _selectedFrame = value;
            UpdateAvailableDirections();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateAvailableDirections()
{
    // store the selected direction
    var previouslySelectedDirection = SelectedDirection;

    Directions = GetValidDirectionsByFrameType(EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(SelectedFrame));
    SelectedDirection = GetSelectedDirection(previoslySelectedDirection, Directions);
}

private string[] GetValidDirectionsByFrameType(FrameType frameType)
{
    return frameType == FrameType.Road ? DirectionsRoad : DirectionsAll; 
}

private string GetSelectedDirection(string previouslySelectedDirection, string[] validDirections)
{
    return validDirections.Contains(previouslySelectedDirection) ? previouslySelectedDirection : DefaultDirection;
}
```

By setting the `SelectedItem` instead of fiddling with the indices, the correct values shall be displayed.

Concerning your question whether this logic may be better suited in an event handler or in the setter depends on your requirements. If all you need is the index, the event `SelectedIndexChanged` may work out for you, but if the value is needed in several places and methods that are not called by the event handler, the presented solution may be more viable.

### Edit

You were correct, it has got nothing to do with the usage of `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem`. The issue is a bit more subtle.

I build a quick proof-of-concept and found the following:

- Assuming `SelectedDirection` is `"Right"` (and the index is set accordingly)
- When `Directions` is set, the `SelectedItem` on the picker seems to be reset
- `SelectedDirection` is set to `null`
- `this.Directions.Contains(value)` evaluates to `false`, hence `_selectedDirection` is not set (this hold true for `SelectedDirectionIndex`, since the value `-1` is filtered by `if(!value < 0 || value >= this.Directions.Count))`
- When `SelectedDirection` is set afterwards, the value is still `"Right"`, hence `OnPropertyChanged` is not called (since the values are the same) and the `SelectedItem` is not set

This way there is a mismatch between the value the `Picker` actually holds and the property in the viewmodel, which leads to unexpected behavior.

#### How to mitigate the issue?

I'd still stick with the code without the indices (unless you really need them) and use the string values.

There are other possibilities, but I'd change the setter of `SelectedDirection`. When you allowed the value to be set to `null`, `PropertyChanged` will be raised properly when the value is set to `Right` afterwards. If you really need to filter what the value is set to, you should still raise `OnPropertyChanged`, to inform the `Picker` that the value has changed (preventing a mismatch between the actual `Picker`s value and the viewmodel)

```cs
public string SelectedDirection
{
    get => _selectedDirection;
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedDirection != value)
        {
            if(Directions.Contains(value))
            {
                _selectedDirection = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedDirection = DirectionTypes.Right.ToString();
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added some **notes** to the question to clarify some of your questions (comment section does not allow enough characters). As for why I used `!DirectionsRoad.Contains`, in the constructor from my view model, I set SelectedDirection to a default value, and that check is to handle the **highly unlikely** (but possible) situation where this default value is not in `DirectionsRoad`. I'll edit the code back to using just the `SelectedItem` and let you know if that works.

Comment: Used your suggestion of removing the use of `SelectedIndex` but that didn't work. However, I did find a somewhat hacky fix for this issue, and thanks for your note on using Events vs logic in the **Setter**.

Comment: Hmm interesting suggestion with your edit, I will try this out and get back to you on whether it worked for me, it definitely feels less **hacky** than what I currently have.

Comment: Very helpful suggestion, I tried this and it worked, explanation also makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Found a somewhat ***hacky*** fix for this, and it seems to be a `Xamarin` issue. I have made the following changes to my code"

The relevant changes are in the setter for `SelectedFrame`:

```
public string SelectedFrame
{
    get { return _selectedFrame; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedFrame != value)
        {
            _selectedFrame = value;
            if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(_selectedFrame) == FrameType.Road)
            {
                Directions = DirectionsRoad;
                if (Directions.Contains(SelectedDirection))
                {
                   /*Relevant edits*/
                    var position = Directions.IndexOf(SelectedDirection);
                    SelectedDirection = Directions[Directions.Count - position -1];
                    SelectedDirection = Directions[position];
                }
                else
                {
                     SelectedDirectionIndex = Directions.IndexOf(DirectionType.Right.ToString());
                }
              }else if (EnumUtils.ToEnumFromString<FrameType>(_selectedFrame) == FrameType.Lane)
              {
                  Directions = DirectionsAll;
                  /*Relevant edits*/
                  var position = Directions.IndexOf(SelectedDirection);
                  SelectedDirection = Directions[Directions.Count - position -1];
                  SelectedDirection = Directions[position];
              }
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

It seems that my issue arises when I change the contents of my `ObservableCollectoin` but the `SelectedDirection` stays the same.

When I change `Directions` (which is an `ObservableCollection`) by assigning it to `DirectionsAll` (also an `ObservableCollection`), I need to make sure that the `SelectedDirection` changes,. The added code ensures that a change actually occurs to `SelectionDirection` and that fixes it. Seems somewhat hacky but it works.

**Outcome:**

[image: Fix video]

Comment: Your conclusion is only partially correct. It has nothing to do with `ObservableCollection`, this would only fire if you changed the contents, but this is not what you do, you are assigning another collection. What happens is that when you set the `Directions` the `SelectedItem` will be reset. Somehow (indeed a Xamarin issue) the bound property is not reset accordingly and when you set it to `"Right"`, `OnPropertyChanged` is not called, since `"Right"` is the value it already contains.

Comment: Not a Xamarin issue. I'm preparing an edit to my answer.

Comment: Please see my edit, I explained how this behavior arises and how it can be mitigated.